# How to Do Transitions Between Tabbed Pages in Ionic Framework

Tags: javascript, html, css, ionic-framework

Within the Ionic Framework, you can setup tabs. The pages within the tabs can easily transition using a `slide-left-right` or some other type of transition. This makes the application feel smooth and thought-out.

The issue that I have is that the pages associated with each tab, once clicked from the tab menu, do not transition at all, there is just **boom**: a page.

I found a pen on codepen [(link to codepen demo)](http://codepen.io/calendee/pen/IAjoL) that can replicate this effect as I want it (to some degree), but I cannot replicate it in any scenario, much less the Ionic rc0 (1.0) version.

The codepen code uses an animation that seems to not work elsewhere:

```html
<ion-nav-view animation="slide-left-right"></ion-nav-view>
```

Please assist.

Comment: I think this issue is still, as of now, unresolved. There are so many different related questions / github issues / ionic forum threads running regarding to this problem that I'm getting the feeling that the Ionic team is ignoring this issue alltogether on purpose (for some reason) and hope it dies out..

Comment: Any updates OP? Or does it remain a mystery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tried to get that exact example working, but I achieved a similar effect in one of my apps by giving all the tabs the same view name:

app.js

```
$stateProvider
.state('signin', {
  url: "/sign-in",
  templateUrl: "sign-in.html",
  controller: 'SignInCtrl'
})
.state('forgotpassword', {
  url: "/forgot-password",
  templateUrl: "forgot-password.html"
})
.state('tabs', {
  url: "/tab",
  abstract: true,
  templateUrl: "tabs.html"
})
.state('tabs.home', {
  url: "/home",
  views: {
    'tab-view': {
      templateUrl: "home.html",
      controller: 'HomeTabCtrl'
    }
  }
})
.state('tabs.facts', {
  url: "/facts",
  views: {
    'tab-view': {
      templateUrl: "facts.html"
    }
  }
})
.state('tabs.facts2', {
  url: "/facts2",
  views: {
    'tab-view': {
      templateUrl: "facts2.html"
    }
  }
})
.state('tabs.about', {
  url: "/about",
  views: {
    'tab-view': {
      templateUrl: "about.html"
    }
  }
})
```

tabs.html

```
<ion-tabs tabs-style="tabs-icon-top" tabs-type="tabs-positive" animation="slide-left-right">

    <ion-tab title="Home" icon="ion-home" href="#/tab/home">
      <ion-nav-view name="tab-view"></ion-nav-view>
    </ion-tab>

    <ion-tab title="About" icon="ion-ios7-information" href="#/tab/about">
      <ion-nav-view name="tab-view"></ion-nav-view>
    </ion-tab>

  </ion-tabs>
```

Notice the name "tab-view" for each state and again as the name attribute on the `ion-nav-view` in each tab.

Answer (score 2):

This helped me to find a solution https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/2997 . The trick is to load all tabs in single view. You can't use ion-tabs directive to achieve that, you you will have to create your tab container using regular html:

```
<ion-view title="Tabs Controller">
<!-- All tabs are going to load here -->
<ion-nav-view name="menuContent"></ion-nav-view>

<!-- TABS -->
<div class="tabs-stable tabs-icon-top tabs-bottom tabs-standard">
    <div class="tab-nav tabs">
        <a class="tab-item" ng-click="goTabForums()" ng-class="{ active : settings.isTab1}">
            <i class="icon bb-ios-forums"></i>
            <span translate="TABS.FORUMS_TAB"></span>
        </a>
        <a class="tab-item" ng-click="goTabGroups()" ng-class="{ active : settings.isTab2 }">
            <i class="icon bb-ios-forums"></i>
            <span translate="TABS.GROUPS_TAB"></span>
        </a>
        <a class="tab-item" ng-click="goTabTopics()" ng-class="{ active : settings.isTab2 }">
            <i class="icon bb-ios-topics"></i>
            <span translate="TABS.TOPICS_TAB"></span>
        </a>
        <a class="tab-item" ng-click="goTabNotifications()" ng-class="{ active : settings.isTab2 }">
            <i class="icon bb-ios-notifications"></i>
            <span translate="TABS.NOTIFICATIONS_TAB"></span>
        </a>
        <a class="tab-item" ng-click="goTabProfile()" ng-class="{ active : settings.isTab2 }">
            <i class="icon bb-ios-my-profile"></i>
            <span translate="TABS.MY_PROFILE_TAB"></span>
        </a>
        <a class="tab-item" ng-click="goTabMore()" ng-class="{ active : settings.isTab2 }">
            <i class="icon bb-ios-more"></i>
            <span translate="TABS.MORE_TAB"></span>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

your tabs controller should look like this:

```
.controller('tabsCtrl', function($scope, $ionicConfig, $state) {

$scope.goTabForums = function(){
    $ionicConfig.views.transition('platform');
    $state.go('tabsController.forums');
}
$scope.goTabGroups = function(){
    $ionicConfig.views.transition('platform');
    $state.go('tabsController.groups');
}
$scope.goTabTopics = function(){
    $ionicConfig.views.transition('platform');
    $state.go('tabsController.topics');
}
$scope.goTabNotifications = function(){
    $ionicConfig.views.transition('platform');
    $state.go('tabsController.notifications');
}
$scope.goTabProfile = function(){
    $ionicConfig.views.transition('platform');
    $state.go('tabsController.profile');
}
$scope.goTabMore = function(){
    $ionicConfig.views.transition('platform');
    $state.go('tabsController.more');
}})
```

And finally routs:

```
$stateProvider
.state('tabsController.forums', {
url: '/forums',
views: {
  'menuContent': {
    templateUrl: 'templates/forums.html',
    controller: 'forumsCtrl'
  }
}})
.state('tabsController.topics', {
url: '/topics',
views: {
  'menuContent': {
    templateUrl: 'templates/topics.html',
    controller: 'topicsCtrl'
  }
}})
```